# Anchor says deployed but can't find it on sol explorer

Tags: deploy

I deploy a program, and get the program ID back. But when i try to search the devnet it is never deployed.

```
Program Id: Hxcpf8xPXRxqaoCGE4dARpkpCau6ojuwCGLZcqoKSdHx

Deploy success
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are deploying the program to the devnet an not in your local validator? can you run the deploy with the provider.cluster flag to be sure?:

```
anchor deploy --provider.cluster devnet
```

Comment: ya that fixed it, i thought if i set my config to devnet it would auto deploy on devnet